# SpriteKit/Obj-C -Restarting game in touches began with nodesatPoint

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I ma having trouble restarting my game with my SKSpriteNode playAgainButton with a name property of "play". The game over method is working fine, but I cannot restart the game in the touches began function. Here are the respective functions. Any help would be great, I have been stuck for a while on this problem and have tried several different methods in the doc including - (CGPoint)convertPoint:(CGPoint)point fromNode:(SKNode *)node; and - (NSArray *)nodesAtPoint:(CGPoint)p;

Here is the code I have in the touches began function:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

//    Jumping fucntionality

    [mainChar.physicsBody applyForce:CGVectorMake(0, 75000)];

//    Play Again Button functionality

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    SKNode *node;
    NSArray *nodes = [node nodesAtPoint:location];

    for (node in nodes) {

    if ([node.name isEqual: @"play"]){
        score = 0;
        [node removeFromParent];
        [self.yourScoreLabel removeFromParent];
        [self.finalScoreLabel removeFromParent];
        self.scene.view.paused = NO;
        scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score %ld", (long)score];
        [self startTimers];
    }
    }
}
```

And the gameOver function :

```
-(void)gameOver{

    self.scene.view.paused = YES;

    [planetTimer invalidate];
    [asteroidTimer invalidate];

    self.yourScoreLabel = [SKLabelNode new];
    self.yourScoreLabel.position = CGPointMake(0, 200);
    self.yourScoreLabel.fontSize = 100;
    self.yourScoreLabel.zPosition = 1;
    self.yourScoreLabel.text = @"Your score:";
    [self addChild:self.yourScoreLabel];

    self.finalScoreLabel = [SKLabelNode new];
    self.finalScoreLabel.position = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    self.finalScoreLabel.fontSize = 200;
    self.finalScoreLabel.zPosition =1;
    self.finalScoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)score];
    [self addChild:self.finalScoreLabel];

    SKSpriteNode * playAgainButton = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"play"];
    playAgainButton.position = CGPointMake(0, -200);
    playAgainButton.name = @"play";
    playAgainButton.zPosition = 1;
    [self addChild:playAgainButton];
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: 1) I would do it in the touchedEnded event, not the touchesBegan event.  From a UX (User experience) standpoint, I may accidentally touch the button, and wand to slide off it before releasing my finger to not activate it. 2)  I do not get what "restarts" your game,  all you are doing is restarting a timer, and your main character is still accelerating from the last time you touched the screen.

Comment: Easiest and safest way to restart the game, is to create a new gamescene instance

Comment: Thank you @Knight0fDragon touchesEnded makes sense. Yeah it is not a true "restart" but it resets score, timers etc and starts again from there. My problem is the nodesatPoint method , I changed it to call on self i.e SKSpriteNode *node = [self nodesatPoint:location] now it is returning the array, however it is not recognizing my "play" node restart button from the location.

Comment: Because you are using `locationInView` not `locationInNode`  where the node is your scene

Comment: Thanks for the help! I fixed it with this line :NSArray *nodes = [self nodesAtPoint:[self convertPointFromView:location]]; ... I had to convert the point

Comment: no, use locationInNode `CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `[touch locationInView:view]` which will return the location in the view's coordinate system.  In SpriteKit, you need to work off of the scenes's coordinate system,  which may be at a different interval.  To get the location in the scene, simply do `CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];`